# how to create the cassandra-jar from the cassandra source code?

Tags: maven, ant, jar, cassandra, build-process

I have made some changes to the Cassandra source code and I want to include these changes into the Hadoop cluster.For that I want to create jars from this updated source code.

Can I have the steps for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want to know how to build a Cassandra jar? From the root of the Cassandra source tree run:

```
ant jar
```

This will drop the jar file in the build directory.